# Using ObjectDataSource in ASP .NET 3.5 - looking for thorough code samples with validation

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I'm looking for an ASP .NET 3.5 book that would cover thoroughly (with advanced code samples) how to use ObjectDataSource with variety of business scenarios. Do you know any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx) could be enough, don't think it's worth to buy a book just for that :)

[Here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/basic-reporting/displaying-data-with-the-objectdatasource-cs) you have an ASP.NET specific post.

ASP.NET validation controls are totally independent to `ObjectDataSource`. If you send more details about your specific scenario, we could help better.

Comment: I just took over a project that is a mess, and I haven't used ObjectDataSource at all. There are forms, and if you provide wrong values like string into price input, exceptions are thrown. Also, there's no error handling when CRUD methods fail. So I'm looking for ALL-IN-ONE sample :) My first thought was to ask on StackOverflow :)